# How to create new tags if not present in autocomplete Boostrap tags input typeahead

Tags: typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

HTML:

```html
<div class="category-container">
    <input type="text" id="category" />
    <div id='tes'>Check Value
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"city":"Jakarta"},{"id":2,"city":"Washington"},{"id":3,"city":"Amsterdam"},{"id":4,"city":"Sydney"}]
var citynames = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('city'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: $.map(data, function (city) {
        return {
                id: city.id,
            city: city.city
        };
    })
});
citynames.initialize();

$('.category-container > input').tagsinput({
    typeaheadjs: [{
          minLength: 1,
          highlight: true,
    },{
        minlength: 1,
        name: 'citynames',
        displayKey: 'city',
        valueKey: 'city',
        source: citynames.ttAdapter()
    }]
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tes').click(function(){
        console.log($('#category').val());
    })
})
```

If value is present (for example Sydney, then give the input value of ID, in this case 4), but if the value is not present, give the string inputted.

Example:
if I input Jakarta and new tag such as Kairo, then the value of input will be 1,Kairo.

How to do this?

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wug8mnss/

Comment: See my answer below ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin feature to do that, but you can easily do it yourself simply by rebuilding the tagsinput `val()` string, and insert the `id` of existing values instead of the value itself.

```js
$('#tes').click(function(){
   var newValues = [], values = $('#category').val().split(',')
   function getVal(value) {
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].city == value) return data[i].id
      }
      return value
   }
   newValues = values.map(function(value) {
     return getVal(value) 
   }).join(',')
   console.log(newValues)
})
```

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/wug8mnss/2/**
This console out for example

```
1, Kairo, 4
```

instead of

```
Jakarta, Kairo, Sydney
```